# Gradle subproject dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I am most definitely a gradle newbie [trying to teach myself]; thought I'd start with what I thought would be an extremely simple excercise!
I have a main project (rootproj), and 2 subprojects (mysub and othersub).
I have managed to get the compile/build step working ok ... the jar files get created.
Now I need to copy the jar files into a predefined/existing folder tree, before tar/gzip'ing the folder tree. This is where I get stuck ... cannot figure out how to call the 'tasks' to copy the jar files.

Here's my settings.gradle and build.gradle file contents:-

### settings.gradle

```
include 'othersub'
include 'mysub'
include 'rootproj'
```

### mysub build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':mysub')
    compile files('ext_lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar')
    ...
    compile files('ext_lib/jsonjava.jar')
}

jar {
    archiveName 'myjar.jar'
}

task copymyjars(type: Copy) {
    println 'In copymyjar'
    from 'build/libs/myjar.jar'
    from 'mysub/build/libs/mysub.jar'
    into '../mydir/lib'
}

task copyotherjar(type: Copy) {
    println 'In copyotherjar'
    from 'othersub/build/libs/othersub.jar'
    into '../mydir/other/lib'
}

copymyjars.dependsOn ":.build"
copyotherjar.dependsOn ":othersub.build"
```

### othersub buid.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    archiveName 'othersub.jar'
}
```

No doubt I'm doing something stupid, but what is it?

Comment: What's the problem with `gradle copymyjars`?

Comment: @Aseem Bansal the problem I have, is that neither of the 2 copyxxx tasks are getting called, and I cannot figure out how to call them after the build has completed. Thanks

Comment: Got it working now.
Instead of using dependsOn, I changed to using task.execute() from within a build.doLast() method.
Possibly not the best way to do it, but it works!
Thanks Aseem for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
task copymyjars(type: Copy, dependsOn :[jar]) {
    from 'build/libs/myjar.jar'
    from 'mysub/build/libs/mysub.jar'
    into '../mydir/lib'
}
```

Depend on `Jar` task, and then copy your `jars` to your directory